# How to fit linear mixed model with nested fixed factors with lme4

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme

I'm using linear mixed model with the lme4 package in R to analyze **EEG amplitude** in two different subject groups (control & experiment).

All subjects were instructed to view images of two different categories (car vs human). While category 1 solely comprises of whole cars, category 2 can then be divided into three sub-categories (head, trunk, extremities).

My dataset looks like this:

| Amplitude | Group | Category | Sub-category | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13.231 | control | car | car | 1 |
| 12.123 | control | car | car | 1 |
| 11.876 | control | human | head | 1 |
| 18.423 | control | human | trunk | 1 |
| 14.132 | control | human | extr | 1 |
| 13.231 | exper | car | car | 2 |
| 12.123 | exper | car | car | 2 |
| 11.876 | exper | human | head | 2 |
| 18.423 | exper | human | trunk | 2 |
| 14.132 | exper | human | extr | 2 |
| 13.412 | exper | car | car | 3 |
| 12.534 | exper | car | car | 3 |
| 19.233 | exper | human | head | 3 |
| 15.423 | exper | human | trunk | 3 |
| 17.122 | exper | human | extr | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Now I am interested in the **effect of group, category, as well as sub-category on EEG amplitude**. I am also interested in the interaction between group and category, and group and sub-category.

Hence, I would like to define category and sub-category as fixed effects. My current model looks like this:

`AMP.model = lmer(amplitude ~ group * (category + subcategory) + (1|patient), data=AMP)`

But then i receive the following warning:

`fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients`

I believe this is due to the assumption in linear mixed models that fixed effects should not be correlated / nested. But how else would I get the information that I am interested in?

Please note that it is not an option to remove the categories and only check for sub-categories, as my main hypothesis is based on the effects of categories on EEG amplitude.

Comment: Seems to me your model is over-specified, and that's why you get a singular fit. I suggest using `amplitude ~ group * category + group:category:subcategory + (1|patient)` I don't think you need to set up special model contrasts, and the **emmeans** package will detect the nested structure and provide for sensible means and comparisons.

Comment: Actually I think the **emmeans** package will deal with the singular model you have, detect the nesting structure, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way around the constraint *at the stage of fitting the model*; however, you should still be able to answer the questions you want. Since this problem is not specific to mixed models (i.e. it applies just as well to a simple linear model with the same structure), I'll illustrate with your data above in an `lm()` fit:

Set up a custom contrast matrix: I find it's easier to define these by defining the *inverse* contrast matrix first.

```r
contr_inv <- matrix(c(
    1/2, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6,
    1,-1/3,-1/3,-1/3,
    0, 2/3,-1/3,-1/3,
    0, -1/3,2/3,-1/3),
    byrow=TRUE,nrow=4,
    dimnames=list(c("intercept","group","head_vs_mean","trunk_vs_mean"),
                  unique(dd$Sub.category))
    )
```

The first contrast is the overall intercept, treating the groups as units (1/2 * mean of group 1 + 1/2 * mean of the subcategories in group 2; the second contrast is the comparison between groups. Contrasts 3 and 4 are the comparisons between the first two subcategories of group 2 and the mean of the other two groups.

Set up a factor and assign the contrasts:

```r
dd$Sub.category <- factor(dd$Sub.category,
                          levels=unique(dd$Sub.category))
contrasts(dd$Sub.category) <- solve(contr_inv)[,-1]
```

```r
summary(m1 <- lm(Amplitude ~ Sub.category, data=dd))
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)                14.2012     0.5606  25.334 4.18e-11 ***
## Sub.categorygroup          -2.8510     1.1211  -2.543   0.0273 *  
## Sub.categoryhead_vs_mean   -1.2983     1.0028  -1.295   0.2219    
## Sub.categorytrunk_vs_mean   1.7963     1.0028   1.791   0.1008
```

This doesn't completely solve your problem, as you might want to (1) test whether there is an overall difference among subcategories within group 1 (which would translate to testing the *joint* null hypothesis that the two subcategory parameters (`head_vs_mean` and `trunk_vs_mean`) were both 0, which is normally done by testing whether the *sum of squares* of the parameters is zero) and (2) test the difference of the third subcategory (`extr`) from the mean of group 2. You can use `multcomp::glht()` or possibly `emmeans` to construct these differences, but I haven't gotten to that yet ...